# Getting 404-Not Found Error on running Oracle APE X Application

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-apex, database-administration

I have started learning oracle APEX and installed oracle apex 20.2 on my desktop PC just now. I am facing a problem that on running a sample application after install it shows me 404 - Not Found error.
[image]
Can anybody help me on this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this issue. Actually the issue was with the user rights. I created a new user other the APEX_PUBLIC_USER and then the APEX was not working well because my new user didn't have those rights which APEX_PUBLIC_USER has.

I solved it by configuring the APEX back to the APEX_PUBLIC_USER and it runs well.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue when I imported an application. Try this: in application properties untick "Friendly URLs" and run it again.

If you're still getting the issue show the end of your url (all parameters after the server).